# Program type already present: com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm trying to integrate a Unity project into an already existing Android Studio project. I get this error when I try to run the application:

> Program type already present: com.unity3d.player.BuildConfig

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue when I had Unity Monetization 3.0.1 (for ads) imported along with the "Build in extension enabled" please refer to the pic.

To resolve the issue 
-I disabled the "built-in Ads extension"
- delete the android and ios folders in the plugin folder and 
- reimport the monetization package to make it work.

There is a conflict between the built in package and the one we download from the asset store. Hope this helps someone.

[image: Disable the built-in extension if you are using Monetization package from asset store]

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue. My project had a library module which had the same package name as the app module. This was creating the conflict. After I change the library name in the AndroidManifest, it compiled.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have imported two modules with same package name

Answer (score 0):

usually it can happen if you have libraries that use different versions of a gradle dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I solve the issue by removing unity ads package from package manager.

edit: In my case monetization plugin and package manager's Unity Ads extension was conflicting. hope it helps